# Ruby on Rails: How to purge entries from search box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a search box using the following form:

```
<div id='search-box'>
  <%= form_tag "/search", :method => :get, :id => "search-form" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], {:id => "search-text", :placeholder => "SEARCH FOR PRODUCTS"} %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

The problem is that whenever I type something in the search box, it shows a dropdown with previous queries. I do not want to store the queries and show the dropdown. How can I purge the queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `autocomplete="off"`:

`<%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], {:id => "search-text", :placeholder => "SEARCH FOR PRODUCTS", :autocomplete => 'off'} %>`

Comment: Thanks, this works. But, I plan to use [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to give the dropdown for autocomplete at a later point. I guess this will turn off autocomplete completely

Comment: ehm, I don't think so. Solr doesn't know if you call it from terminal, server or a client with javascript. So you have to turn it off, even for solr ;)

Comment: @23tux this turns off the browser's built-in autocomplete. When you start using solr you'd need a javascript autocomplete plugin, e.g. http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/